# Laravel 6 perform role based routing

Tags: laravel, sentinel

I have a route group with different routes. I want to have different role levels access without changing the URL of the application.

For example I want to have /admin as the route and then I want to allow or disallow users based on their roles. Basically, I want every user to be able to see the same page but with different menu options(I know how to do this) but also secure the links from direct access.

Is there a nice way to achieve that without the need of using different middlewares seperately on each route? Since there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the $request variable inside the web.php file but only inside a controller. I'm using the sentinel package for auth.

Some sample code of my web.php:

```
Route::group(
['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'customer', 'as' => 'admin.'],
function () {
    // Ad list
    Route::get('getMyAnnonsList', 'Admin\BackEndController@getMyAdList')->name('getMyAdList');       
    }
);
```

Great answer by @lagbox. This is what I did in the end. Very elegant.

web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
Route::middleware('admin:admin,user')->group(function(){
            Route::get('getMyAnnonsList', 'Admin\BackEndController@getMyAdList')->name('getMyAdList'); 
        });
});
```

middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{      
    if (!Sentinel::check()) 
        return redirect('admin/signin')->with('info', 'You must be logged in!');
     
    foreach($roles as $role)        
        if($role == Sentinel::getUser()->roles[0]->slug)
            return $next($request);        
   
    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `request()` helper method in the web.php file? Or even `Route::group`'s?

Comment: Yes. The $request variable doesn't include authentication information while on web.php. This is by design of Laravel: web.php->route->middleware->controller. So I tried to populate the request variable in the middleware and that works but its only accessible in the controller since it doesnt go back to the web.php file after the middleware.

Comment: Yeah I didn't consider that issue, but more specifically, you seem to have an issue with having to declare a middleware "on each route", so are you not using Resourceful Routing, Route Groups, or declaring middleware in your Controller::__constructor()'s, these are all designed to reduced the burden of declaring middleware. If that is not your issue please clarify.

Comment: i am not sure what the actual issue here is ... what different middleware are you referring to?

Comment: The main issue is that I want to allow different roles inside a route group in the web-php file, and then allow access to different links / routes depending on the user role. One way to do this is to create the same group with 2 different middlewares and include different routes in each group. I wonder if I could do this using one single group with all the routes and using a simple if statement, to allow or disallow access.

Comment: this is what middleware is for ... do you know which roles you want to allow access to what? middleware can take parameters ... there is also ways to set specific arbitrary information on the route at definition and access it via the middleware

Comment: Can I pass parameters to each route in order to let the middleware decide whether to allow access or not? I added some code in my question. for example can I check the name of the route in order to determine access inside the middleware?

Comment: you could assign a middleware to the entire group, that middleware could check the route for specific information and act accordingly, you can do that ... i will post an example as an answer or find a post i already did with that same thing

Comment: Thank you. I found out that I can get the name of the route in the middleware as simply as like this: $request->route()->getName(). This is enough for me. Write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already answered something like this before, should be working the same still.

You can create a middleware that can be applied to your group. In that middleware it is asking the route itself for the specific roles to check.

[How to assign two middleware to the same group of routes. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737410/2109233)

Example of middleware:

```
class CheckMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $roles = $request->route()->getAction('roles', []);

        foreach ((array) $roles as $role) {
            // if the user has this role, let them pass through
            if (...) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        // user is not one of the matching 'roles'
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Example route definition:

```
Route::middleware('rolescheck')->group(function () {
    Route::get('something', ['uses' => 'SomeController@method', 'roles' => [...]])->name(...);
});
```

You can apply this arbitrary data at the group level, the individual route level or both, as all routes are individually registered; groups just allow for cascading of configuration.

You could also have this middleware take parameters, and just merge them with the arbitrary roles, then it is a dual purpose middleware:

```
public function handle($request, $next, ...$roles)
{
    $roles = array_merge($roles, $request->route()->getAction('roles', []));
    ...
}

Route::middleware('rolescheck:admin,staff')->group(...);
```

Comment: Wow this was even better than I thought. Great answer!

Comment: I hope it helps you out :)

Comment: @m33ts4k0z i added a further update to allow you to use this as a regular role check middleware that you can pass parameters to as well

Comment: Thank you. I tested your first example on this post and it worked like a charm. I will use your latest example with middleware groups since I have many routes and it would take some time to rewrite them in order to use the ['uses' => ...] format.

Comment: no problem, you have like 3 different ways to go about it with that 1 middleware, so you should be okay ... and from the linked answer make sure to notice how they can be cascaded, if needed (where it is adding up all the roles for each nested group)

Comment: The cascading is great but it is not needed at the moment since I only have 2 roles. I will update my question with my final working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Laravel Gate And Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization)

You can define the gate inside the `App > Providers > AuthServiceProvider`

and you can also create policies per `CRUD`. just see info in `php artisan help make:policy`. This will create a folder in your `app` called policies you can define the who can access it.

In your controller you can do is this: (this is a gate middleware)

I define the gate first:

```php
Gate::define('check', function ($user, $request) {
  return $user->roles->contains('name', $request) || $user->roles->contains('name', 'root');
});
```

then I initialise it in the controller

```php
abort_if(Gate::denies('check', 'admin only'), 403);
```

This will throw 403 error if the user don't have access on that role. It will check if the user has `admin only` role. If it doesn't have it will throw the error

In your view if you want to disable `anchor links` you can do like this:

```html
@can('check', 'admin only')
  <a href="/admin/dashboard">dashboard</a>
@endcan
```

EDIT:
**Controller**

```php
public function index() {
  abort_if(Gate::denies('check', 'admin only'), 403);
  // Your Code...
}
```

Comment: The original problem remains: This has to be done in the controller since there is no authenticated user when the route is chosen inside the web.php